# How to disable Class inside Input(Radio) Button in Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, radio-button

I need to Disable KG Value Radio button using **qusweitstnesel** class name. Here is my code

**HTML**

```
<li id="field_1_48" class="gfield qusweitstnesel gfield_contains_required field_sublabel_below field_description_below gfield_visibility_visible" style="display: list-item;">
<label class="gfield_label">Weight<span class="gfield_required">*</span></label>
<div class="ginput_container ginput_container_radio">
<ul class="gfield_radio" id="input_1_48">
<li class="gchoice_1_48_0">
<input name="input_48" value="KG" id="choice_1_48_0" tabindex="13" disabled="disabled" class="gf-default-disabled" type="radio">
<label for="choice_1_48_0" id="label_1_48_0">KG</label>
</li>
<li class="gchoice_1_48_1">
<input name="input_48" value="Stone" checked="checked" id="choice_1_48_1" tabindex="14" type="radio">
<label for="choice_1_48_1" id="label_1_48_1">Stone</label>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</li>
```

**JQuery :**

```
var kgs="KG";
jQuery(".qusweitnotsel .ginput_container_radio .gfield_radio li input[type=radio][value='+ kgs +']").attr("disabled","disabled");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use double quotes inside single quotes in `[value='"+ kgs +"']`.

**Please Note:** You already have disabled property set to the radio button in the HTML. You also have typo in the class name used in code as `qusweitnotsel`....should be `qusweitstnesel`

```js
var kgs="KG";
jQuery(".qusweitstnesel .ginput_container_radio .gfield_radio li input[type=radio][value='"+ kgs +"']").attr("disabled","disabled");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<li id="field_1_48" class="gfield qusweitstnesel gfield_contains_required field_sublabel_below field_description_below gfield_visibility_visible" style="display: list-item;">
  <label class="gfield_label">Weight<span class="gfield_required">*</span></label>
  <div class="ginput_container ginput_container_radio">
    <ul class="gfield_radio" id="input_1_48">
      <li class="gchoice_1_48_0">
        <input name="input_48" value="KG" id="choice_1_48_0" tabindex="13" class="gf-default-disabled" type="radio">
        <label for="choice_1_48_0" id="label_1_48_0">KG</label>
      </li>
      <li class="gchoice_1_48_1">
        <input name="input_48" value="Stone" checked="checked" id="choice_1_48_1" tabindex="14" type="radio">
        <label for="choice_1_48_1" id="label_1_48_1">Stone</label>
        </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</li>
```

You also can use [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) which allows embedded expressions:

```js
var kgs="KG";
jQuery(`.qusweitstnesel .ginput_container_radio .gfield_radio li input[type=radio][value=${kgs}]`).attr("disabled","disabled");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<li id="field_1_48" class="gfield qusweitstnesel gfield_contains_required field_sublabel_below field_description_below gfield_visibility_visible" style="display: list-item;">
  <label class="gfield_label">Weight<span class="gfield_required">*</span></label>
  <div class="ginput_container ginput_container_radio">
    <ul class="gfield_radio" id="input_1_48">
      <li class="gchoice_1_48_0">
        <input name="input_48" value="KG" id="choice_1_48_0" tabindex="13" class="gf-default-disabled" type="radio">
        <label for="choice_1_48_0" id="label_1_48_0">KG</label>
      </li>
      <li class="gchoice_1_48_1">
        <input name="input_48" value="Stone" checked="checked" id="choice_1_48_1" tabindex="14" type="radio">
        <label for="choice_1_48_1" id="label_1_48_1">Stone</label>
        </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</li>
```